# Dependency between quantitative and categorial variable

Tags: categorical-data, independence, contingency-tables

I have a data set with a categorical variable $C$ (approx. 8 levels) and a quantitative variable $X$. I suspect that $X$ and $C$ are strongly dependent. How can I verify this hypothesis?

My approach would be to 'bin' $X$ in order to obtain about the same number of categories as for $C$ and then use a test for contingency tables.

Once I have established depedency I would like to find 'the natural order' of the categories of $C$ implied by $X$, or even to assign distances between the levels of $C$, based on the numeric scale of $X$. Can this idea be made rigorous? Does it make sense?

Comment: A *poor man's* approach to backing into this concern would be to treat *X* as a dependent variable and *C* as independent thus making them amenable to ANOVA. By taking the square root of the resulting R-square value from that simple model their correlation can be derived.

Answer (score 1):

ALL  EDITED:

The poster has made clear in the comments below that they are looking for a test of association that doesn't assume one variable is independent and one is dependent.

This is probably a duplicate of [this Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables/102800).  There is some helpful discussion there.  There are some good option at [this other CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/correlation-coefficient-for-non-dichotomous-nominal-variable-and-ordinal-numeric).

To meet the Poster's criteria, maybe one approach would be to use an extended version of the Cochran-Armitage test that allows for more than two categories.  For this test, one variable is ordinal and the other is nominal, arranged in a contingency table, so it would still require reducing the quantitative variable to an ordinal one, perhaps with some binning.  But I think this approach is closer than reducing the continuous variable to a categorical one.  From what I read, it's a test of association that doesn't assume that one variable is dependent.

An appropriate measure of association for the ordinal/nominal case may be Freeman's theta.

An appropriate measure of association for the interval/nominal case may be eta-squared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From my understanding all proposed tests would treat C as independent and X as dependent variable, i.e try to explain X by observations of C. Are there any ‘symmetric’ measures of association between X and C or is this too much to ask for?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I think your answer was informative even before the edit. Maybe you should combine old + new answer into a single one.