# correlation between a continuous and a binary variable

Tags: correlation, binary-data, continuous-data

I am interested between the correlation between a continuous variable and a binary variable (female=1/male=2).

I think it doesn't really make sense to calculate it like this:

```
cor.test(data$continuousvariable,data$binaryvariable)
```

Is correlation only used for two continous variables? What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correlation coefficient between a (non-dichotomous) nominal variable and a numeric (interval) or an ordinal variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/correlation-coefficient-between-a-non-dichotomous-nominal-variable-and-a-numer)

Comment: Or this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables/102800 (first one shows a non-dichotomous case).